# How to allocate a 3 dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Creating two dimensional arrays in C is easy:

```
char (*arr)[50] = malloc(sizeof(arr) * 10 * 50); // 10x50 matrix
```

How do you do three dimensional arrays in C? It doesn't look like I can do something like:

```
char (**arr)[50] = malloc(sizeof(arr) * 10 * 20 * 50); // 10x20x50 matrix?
```

Comment: `sizeof(char) * 10 * 50` would be a 10x50 matrix of characters, no?

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner It would be. :) But it's a 2-dim matrix. But I wonder how to do 3-dim...

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's the same as writing sizeof(char). (Edit: I think)

Comment: Why not add the * 20 as in your second snippet, but with sizeof(char) instead? Does that not work? I'm not trying to sound sarcastic either, just trying to help :)

Comment: a simple googling will give this excellent article: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html

Comment: `arr` is a pointer, so its size is not the same as `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: And I agree with the comment somewhere that `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1, so superfluous.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Superfluous, but harmless. I could see how it could aid readability in some cases.

Comment: Sure, harmless and perhaps more readable, I don't know.

Comment: "But it's a 2-dim matrix." -- No it's not.

Comment: @bodacydo it really makes a difference how many of the dimensions are known at compile-time

Answer (score 3):

Three dimensional array requires 2 dimensions to be known

```
char (*arr)[20][50] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10 * 20 * 50)
```

Note: I have corrected sizeof(arr) to sizeof(char), because sizeof(arr) will return the size of a pointer.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always superfluous...

Comment: Yes, I agree. I tend to do this for readability to identify the type allocated. Or more better would be to say malloc(sizeof(char[10][20][30])).

Comment: In that case, you are doing it wrong. `sizeof ***arr` makes some sense, but that *documentation* in the best case becomes stale and *not* wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response! Now I've another question, what if `20` and `30` are not constants but values passed to a function?

Comment: @bodacydo: you should really just follow this recipe here and it will do everything you want - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306802/2591612

Comment: @bodacydo: If you think it is an excellent response, then do the author of the response a favour and upvote it.

Comment: @bodacydo, If the array subscripts are variables, you could do similar syntax in C99, which supports variable sized array. Otherwise you need to manage the 3-dimensions yourselves by allocating a single dimensional array.

Comment: `malloc( sizeof *arr * 10)` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way could be to allocate a mono-dimensional array, e.g.

```
 int width=10; length=20; height=50;
 char* arr = malloc(width*length*height);
 if (!arr) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

then have some way to access it, for instance a macro

```
 #define Element(I,J,K) arr[width*length*(I)+length*(J)+(K)]
```

and use `Element(i,j,k)`

You could pack all this using a [*flexible array member*](http://www.johnfindlay.plus.com/lcc-win32/Tuts/FlexArrs.htm) like

```
 struct my3dstring_st {
   int width;
   int length;
   int height;
   char arr[];
 };
```

then have a.g. a making function

```
  struct my3dstring_st *
  make_my3dstring (int width, int length, int height)
  { 
    if (width<=0 || length<=0 || height<=0) return NULL;
    struct my3dstring_st* s = 
       malloc(sizeof(struct my3dstring_st) 
              + width * length * height);
    if (!s) {perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    s->width = width;
    s->length = length;
    s->height = height;
    memset (s->arr, 0, width * length * height);
    return s;
  }
```

and an inline accessing function (in a header file):

```
  static inline int 
  access_m3dstring(struct my3dstring_st*s, int i, int j, int k) {
     if (!s || i<0 || j<0 || k<0 
         || i>=s->width || j>=s->height || k>=s->length) return EOF;
     return s->arr[i*->width*s->height + j*s->height + k];
   }
```

I leave as an exercise to write the modification function `modify_m3dstring`, and you could have unsafe but faster variants which don't do any checks...

Comment: Thanks this is very cool! Modification function can be as simple as `Element[i,j,k] = x;` :)

Comment: Not if you want to modify some `struct my3dstring_st*` pointer passed as argument. My macro `Element` only works if `arr` is a *global* variable (or a formal parameter but that is ugly).

Comment: `static inline int 
  access_m3dstring(struct my3dstring_st*s, int i, int j, int k, char val) {
     if (!s || i<0 || j<0 || k<0 
         || i>=s->width || j>=s->height || k>=s->length) return EOF;
     s->arr[i*->width*s->height + j*s->height + k] = val;
   }`

Comment: I mean edit_m3dstring! `s->arr[i*->width*s->height + j*s->height + k] = val`. Is the relevant part. And also `char val` in function specification.

Comment: `calloc` is probably better than `malloc` + `memset`. Some operating systems have a more optimal way of providing zero-initialized blocks.

Answer (score 1):

General rules:

```
T *arr         = malloc( sizeof *arr * n ); // for an N-element array
T (*arr)[N]    = malloc( sizeof *arr * m ); // for an NxM-element array
T (*arr)[N][M] = malloc( sizeof *arr * k ); // for an NxMxK-element array
```

where uppercase letters indicate values that are known at compile time and lowercase letters indicate values that are known at run time.  The pattern for higher-dimensional arrays should be obvious.

If you are using C99 compiler or a C2011 compiler that supports variable-length arrays, you can use runtime variables for all your dimensions:

```
size_t n = some_value();
size_t m = some_other_value();
size_t k = yet_another_value();

T (*arr)[n][m] = malloc( sizeof *arr * k );
```

The type of the expression `*arr` is `T [n][m]`, so `sizeof *arr` gives the same result as `sizeof (T) * n * m`; the result is easier to read and less prone to errors.

If your compiler doesn't support VLAs and you don't know your dimensions at compile time, you'll either have to allocate as a 1-d array and compute offsets manually:

```
T *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * n * m * k );
...
arr[ 3*n*m + 2*m + 1] = x; // equivalient to arr[3][2][1] = x
```

Or, if you can live with your rows not being adjacent in memory, you could allocate the array piecemeal:

```
T ***arr = malloc (sizeof *arr * n );
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
  arr[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i] * m );
  for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++ )
  {
    arr[i][j] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i][j] * k )
  }
}
```

Ideally, you should check the result of each `malloc` to make sure it succeeded.  And you'll have to free the array in the reverse order that you allocated it:

Answer (score 0):

```
char (*arr)[20][50] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10 * 20 * 50);
```

`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1. So, it can be omitted.

```
char (*arr)[20][50] = malloc(10 * 20 * 50);
```